# Is the hadith about the People of Iraq becoming fulfilled?

Tags: hadith, day-of-judgement

Al-Humaydi said:

> Muslim narrated a similar hadith via another isnaad from Suhayl from his father from Abu Hurayrah, which was attributed to the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him):
>
> “Iraq will withhold its dirhams and qafeez…”

And he quoted the hadith using the past tense, but what is meant is the future, so as to emphasise that it will surely come to pass. Muslim also narrated from Jaabir in a marfoo‘ report:

> “Soon there will not  be brought to the people of Iraq any camels or dirhams. We said: Why is that? He said: Because the non-Arabs will prevent it.”

The above hadith can means two things:

- **The people of Iraq will become Muslims**
- **The people of Iraq will not get any money or food because of the non-Arabs**

My first bullet point has already happened as the people of Iraq have because Muslims and therefore they do not need to pay Jizya.

This leads to the next bullet point of what the hadith means.

Nowadays with all the conflicts in Iraq and Syria, **countries are not letting in refugees from Iraq** and with ISIS, **countries will not trade with them or even let people go there.**

**Question: Is the hadith about the People of Iraq becoming fulfilled?**

**This will be relevant:**

Ibn Kathir wrote:

> إِذْ لَوْ قَوُوا هَؤُلَاءِ لَأَفْسَدُوا الْأَرْضَ كُلَّهَا عِرَاقًا وَشَامًا وَلَمْ يَتْرُكُوا طِفْلًا وَلَا طِفْلَةَ وَلَا رَجُلًا وَلَا امْرَأَةً لِأَنَّ النَّاسَ عِنْدَهُمْ قَدْ فَسَدُوا فَسَادًا لَا يُصْلِحُهُمْ إِلَّا الْقَتْلُ جُمْلَةً
>
> *If the Khawarij ever gained power, they would corrupt the entire earth, Iraq, and Syria. They would not leave a boy or a girl or a man or a woman, for in their view the people have become so corrupt that they cannot be reformed except by mass killing.*
>
> Source: al-Bidāyah wal-Nihāyah 10/584

Some people relate that ISIS are the modern day Khawarij. See this [article](http://muslimmatters.org/2015/08/24/khawarij-ideology-isis-savagery-part-one/).

*<sub>(Note that the hadith above is part time of a hadith. Click on this [link](https://islamqa.info/en/128708) to find the full hadith and it might help you understand my question.)</sub>*

Comment: While this is a very good question, it leans toward being off-topic as the answer would primarily be opinion based. This is especially the case since the other two countries mentioned in the hadith are Egypt and Syria, and indications point toward what is happening now is a fulfillment of the hadith, but how can we be confident this is the case?

Comment: Should I change the question to be **Is it possible that the hadith of the people of Iraq is being fullfilled due to what is happening nowadays?** or is that leaning towards being primarily opinion based?

Comment: Your second bullet point is very shadily related to what is happening. Among the non arabs giving food to irakis and syrians, you have the turks, germans, swedes, canadians, french,...  Among the arabs denying food to the syrians and irakis you have some other syrians and irakis, as well as some countries of the region.